# Со временем удаляются изображения

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Здравствуйте. Загрузил вчера сайт на heroku. После установки сайта, загружал фото. После некоторого времени изображения удаляются. В чем может быть проблема? Новичок в ruby on rails. Спасибо за внимание :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku не предоставляет место для хранения загружаемых файлов. У вас есть лишь 300мб, выделяемых на slug (подготовленный к запуску проект), и папка /tmp для хранения кеша и свежезагруженных файлов. Эта папка периодически очищается, и ваши файлы, загруженные в нее, пропадают.

Для хранения загружаемых файлов можно использовать [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/s3/), связав его с рельсовым приложением с помощью гемов `fog` или `aws-s3`. Поищите инструкции подключения S3 через эти гемы с вашим загрузчиком файлов (`carrierwave`, `paperclip`).